# Postgres - Return 0 count for intervals with no data in date_trunc

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to create a table that lists how many counts i have in 5 minute intervals over 10 days. I think my join is wrong since i am not getting the empty rows in my query.

```
select date_trunc('minute', activities.activitytime) - 
    (CAST(EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM activities.activitytime)    
    AS integer) % 5) * interval '1 minute' as day_column, count(activities.activityid)

from generate_series(current_date - interval '10 day', current_date, '1 minute') d 

left join activities on date(activities.activitytime) = d 

group by day_column 
order by day_column;
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are close.  But the key idea is that you need to use the columns from the `generate_series()` for the `group by` key:

```
select d.dte, count(a.activitytime)
from generate_series(current_date - interval '10 day', current_date, '5 minute') d(dte) left join
     activities a
     on a.activitytime >= d.dte and a.activitytime < d.dte + interval '5 minute'
group by d.dte 
order by d.dte;
```

Comment: Hm i tried running it and it returns 1 for every interval.

Comment: I fixed the `count()`.  Now it should return 0 or 1.